# Mounting the Thermalright HR-02 Macho cooler on Asus P8Z68-V?

Tags: motherboard, cooling

I just bought a HR-02 Macho for use with my Asus P8Z68-V without completely reading through all the documents on Thermalrights website. Upon trying to mount it on the motherboard, I noticed that there is a metal plate already mounted where the cooler backplate is supposed to be, which makes it impossible to use the cooler. There is apparantly a special backplate that works on the Asus motherboards, but since Thermalright does not seem to be answering my email, I have had no luck in getting hold of one. So my questions:

1. Does anyone know where to get hold of the HR-02 Macho Asus specific backplate?
2. Is there any other way of solving the problem? I read somewhere that some user had solved the problem on a P8Z68-V Pro by removing the plate from the motherboard, but to me it looks like this is what keeps the cpu socket mount affixed to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out that I did not have the correct backplate. It was possible to use it after removing a couple of millimeters from one end of it with an angle grinder though. It was supposed to be mounted on top of the metal plate on the backside of the motherboard.